# Deleting items from tuple using recursion

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.Char


type Games = (String, String, Int)

test :: [Games]
test =
    [
    ("Minecraft","mojang",100),
    ("GTA V","rockstar",500),
    ("Portal","valve",200),
    ("GTA IV","rockstar",100)
    ]

deleteAllInstances :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
deleteAllInstances a (x:xs)
    | a == x    = rest
    | otherwise = x : rest
      where
        rest = deleteAllInstances a xs
deleteAllInstances _ _ = []
```

So I am trying to get `deleteAllInstances` to delete all matches.

For example, if I executed `deleteAllInstances "rockstar"` it should return a list of tuples `[("Minecraft","mojang",100),("Portal","valve",200),]` with all instances of "rockstar" deleted.

So the question is how can i get `deleteAllInstances` to delete "rockstar" and all associated values and output the results?

Comment: This does not sound like a recursive problem. Isnt that just a plain old single run iteration?

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: You aren't filtering by the eq instance on a tuple, you're filtering by the eq instance on the second element. Have you considered using the filter function instead?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the filter function, would you mind showing me? I thought I could use recursion for this. I'm sorry, really new to Haskell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should probably use `filter` for this.

`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` runs through the list, and retains elements that your predicate maps to `True`.

In this instance, you'd want something like this:

`deleteAllInstances :: String -> [Games] -> [Games]
deleteAllInstances string games = filter (\(_,s,_) -> (s /= string)) games`

There's no real need for you to build another function around `filter` here, and your code is probably more readable just using `filter` directly.

You're not using recursion directly here, it is abstracted by `filter`, which is itself a recursive function. A lot of the common uses of recursion are covered by combinations of `filter`, `map` and `fold` functions.

Comment: Thank you, but if I run `deleteAllInstances "rockstar" test` it returns everything that matched `"rockstar"`. What I was trying to ask is how can I get it to show everything except `"rockstar"`.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I put in `==` instead of `/=`. I'll change that now.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like homework, so I'll give you some hints rather than a full solution. Your deleteAllInstances function, as it's currently coded, requires you to pass an entire triple to match, rather than a string  inside it. If you want your function to match and filter based on a string that goes in the second place of a triple, you could deconstruct your list up to the level of the triplets, when you define your parameter matching for your function (you can read more about parameter matching and type deconstruction here: http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions).

But this is something that can be simply implemented in Haskell by using a map and a filter, so explicit recursion wouldn't be the most idiomatic way to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can modify your program to do what you describe:

```
type Games = (String, String, Int)

test :: [Games]
test =
    [
    ("Minecraft","mojang",100),
    ("GTA V","rockstar",500),
    ("Portal","valve",200),
    ("GTA IV","rockstar",100)
    ]

deleteAllInstances :: String -> [Games] -> [Games]
deleteAllInstances a (x:xs)
    | a == x2   = rest
    | otherwise = x : rest
      where
        (x1,x2,x3) = x
        rest = deleteAllInstances a xs
deleteAllInstances _ _ = []
```

Output:

```
*Main> deleteAllInstances "rockstar" test
[("Minecraft","mojang",100),("Portal","valve",200)]
```